# MVC3 unterminated string constant syntax error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, button, razor, url.action

I have the following code which gives me a syntax error - unterminated string constant.I've matched up the quotes can't seem to spot an issue. Any ideas? It works fine, the syntax error is just annoying.

```
  <input type="button" class="my-button" value="" name="back" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(Model.Back.Step.ToString(), "MyController")'" />
```

Comment: **Where** do you get that error? In the browser, the compiler, or  the IDE?

Comment: Is it actually an error?  Or just a squiggly line in the IDE?  Does it compile and run ok?

Comment: just a squiggly red line in the IDE, it runs fine

Comment: For me it was just a squiggly line in the IDE view, and _technically_ worked. However the rendered HTML was all messed up at runtime. It looked like 2 buttons sandwiched in some text. I had to use the solution from @vonv. with the concatenation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
<input type="button" class="my-button" value="" name="back" 
     onclick="@("location.href='" 
        + Url.Action(Model.Back.Step.ToString(), "MyController")  
        + "'")" />
```

Answer (score 12):

Use an actionlink instead. This one creates a nice bootstrap button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Comment: Clean Solution. Thanks for the post