# Unterminated String Constant MVC4 Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on `MVC4` Application (Razor engine). When ever I try to call a js function from a button, it says error :-

> Unterminated string constant

[image]

However it does not give any `compile time` or `runtime` error and works fine.

But on view there it clearly says about above mentioned error:

**why it is so?**

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Razor parser is picky, and in some cases it doesn't correctly parse or color-code the syntax.  Your code will work.

To fix the issue, you can format the code in a way that the parser will know exactly how to figure this out.  Use parentheses around all Razor server-side code references:

```
<input type="button" id="btntest" value="Details"
     onclick="ABC('@(Item.TourApplicationID)', '@(Item.TourID)')" />
```

Edit: above may have only been working in VS 2013, with or without an update.  (or not at all- I just remember it working.

Below should work, taken from [MVC3 unterminated string constant syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420797/mvc3-unterminated-string-constant-syntax-error):

```
<input type="button" id="btntest" value="Details"
     onclick="@("ABC('" & Item.TourApplicationID & "', '" & Item.TourID & "')")" />
```

(I think that's correct.  Hard to tell without the color-coding.)

I prefer string.format, so that onclick would look more like:

```
onclick="@(String.Format("ABC('{0}', '{1}')", Item.TourApplicationID, Item.TourID) )"
```

Comment: error doesn't disappear.It still says the same error.. :(

Comment: Maybe it was something they fixed in VS 2013 in one of the Updates.

Comment: May be, But till now I have never used VS 2013.

Comment: @DeadLock, edited the answer.  This should work for you with VS 2012.

Comment: Because it's a bug.  I tested the original code for the button in VS 2013 Update 3, and I didn't receive an error or a warning.