# HTML button call a controller and action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, html-helper

I have a form and 2 submit buttons. The `Yes` button will display `#modal1` and the `No` button will display `#modal2`. The form need to submit to controller. I refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503923/html-button-calling-an-mvc-controller-and-action-method) in order to solve this. I am using this answer. It 
                    display the modal but the form are not submit

```
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "User")#modal1'" />
```

But the example shows only for `type="button"`. Is there anyway I could do this using submit button?

```
<form Class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" id="myform">
    <input name="eventDate" id="eventDate" Class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" id="btnSearch1" value="search" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btnSearch2" value="search" class="btn btn-success">No</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try this : @Html.ActionLink("DisplayText", "Action", "Controller", route, attribute)

Comment: like this? `<input type="button" value="Create" @Html.ActionLink("DisplayText", "Index", "Home", Nothing, Nothing) />` It still not working

Comment: add submit event
$('#btnSearch1').submit(function() {
  // your code here
});

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `formaction` attribute to solve the issue.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("#", "#", null, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
   //your form element goes here.....
   <button class="ui button" type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("Register", "User")#modal1">Register</button>
   <button class="ui button" type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("Login", "User")#modal2">Login</button>
}
```

Comment: where do I put #modal1 and #modal2?