# get information from form to controller and save it in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I have this code in my html.And i want to post this information from form to controler and save in data base.

```
<form method="POST" class="contactme form-group">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control inputcontact">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Surename" class="form-control inputcontact">
     <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control inputcontact">
     <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{5,10}" class="form-control inputcontact" placeholder="tel. number"><br>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default buttonsend" value="Оставить заявку">
</form>
```

And i have this model:

```
 public int Id { get; }
 public string Firstname { get; set; }
 public string Lastname { get; set; }
 public string Email { get; set; }
 public string Phonenumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: Which `Action` method in your `Controller` do you want to send the data to?

Comment: i don't have Controller yet.Because i don't know what code write in controller

Comment: Well i'll advise you research more into how do all. This place is not for teaching you everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC concept is quite straight forward for achieving what you need. It's usual to have a model that contains properties for the data that you need to display a "View" and also for the content entered by the user so the data can be bound to the model when posted. If you've not got any controller code yet then I would recommend the below approach.

First, write a controller to handle the displaying of your view and the posting of the views form content.

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult YourViewName()
     {
        var myViewModel = new YourViewModel();
        //Populate model data from services etc...

        return View("YourViewName", myViewModel);
     }
}
```

I find it easier to wrap my views data objects that it needs in a class.

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public string Property1 { get; set; }
     public int Property2 { get; set; }
     \\etc...
}
```

Then in your view, wrap your controls in a Form and use Html helper controls to display and bind to the data in the model.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "YourController ", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormName"}))
 {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.YourModel.Property1, null, new { @class = "SomeCssClass"})
    \\Repeat for all properties that need displaying or for user input.
 }
```

You will also need a submit button on the form to post the form to your specified controller.

```
<button id="btnSubmitForm" type="Submit" class="SomeCssClass">Submit</button>
```

Then in your controller you create a method to receive the posted form (Model)

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ActionName(YourViewModel postedContent)
 {

    //Handle saving etc.. here.
    var x = postContent.Property1;
    //Do something with data

    //Re populate model and show updated view.
    var myViewModel = new YourViewModel();

    return View("YourViewName", myViewModel);
 }
```

Thant should help you on your way. A lot of this is down to preference and opinions though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell it which `Controller` and which `Action` in the controller to look for like below:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionMethodHere", "YourControllerHere", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
       <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control inputcontact">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Surename" class="form-control inputcontact">
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control inputcontact">
        <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{5,10}" class="form-control inputcontact" placeholder="tel. number"><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default buttonsend" value="Оставить заявку">
    }
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503923/html-button-calling-an-mvc-controller-and-action-method) should also help

Comment: And what code i should write in controllder?
to get information from input's and save in database?