# Calling Controller method from view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I feel this is a really simple problem, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have a webpage with log entries for each exercise I do in the gym. Date, exercise, weight, reps etc. I can add entries. And I also want to delete a line from the index page by pressing a button. I just want the line to be deleted after clicking delete once and still stay in the index page. But, I don't know how to call my delete method from the index view page.

I added some pseudocode in the last column

```
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var logrow in Model.Take(30))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h6>@logrow.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy")</h6>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h6>@logrow.Exercise</h6>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h6>@logrow.Weight</h6>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h6>@logrow.Repetitions</h6>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h6>@logrow.Sets</h6>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h6>@logrow.Rest_time</h6>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h6>@logrow.Notes</h6>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <*LINK TO METHOD DELETE_LOG_ROW(logrow.id)* class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Delete</span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: You want a button (or link etc) where, if you click it, it will call a method on the controller to delete something? Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You're exactly right !

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503923/html-button-calling-an-mvc-controller-and-action-method

Answer (score 1):

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = logrow.YourID }, null)
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult ActionName(int id)
{
    // delete logic
    return View("ViewName", "ControllerName");

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had actually tried this before making the post. But I wrote "HomeController" as controller name instead of "Home". Beginner struggles :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without page reload in pure ASP.NET MVC.
Use AJAX to prevent this reload.

So your flow looks like

- Call server via ajax to delete entity
- Call server again to get updated entities collection
- Rebuild DOM

Answer (score 0):

You can call ajax and delete item what you want and get updated list from server and return it in form of partial view or Json and rebind your div where you showing your list.