# Simplest way to call a controller method from a view button in .Net (mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I just started programming at MVC and I would like to ask about the best way to call a controller's method from your view.
To make it easier:
I have a model called Song with 2 methods to start and stop it:

```
public class Song
{
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer ;

        public Song() {
            wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            wplayer.URL = "my song url";
            wplayer.controls.stop();
        }
        public void Stop() {
            wplayer.controls.stop();
        }
        public void Start() {
            wplayer.controls.play();
        }
    }
```

In the controller I create the song object and I have two functions to start and stop it.

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Default
            Song c = new Song();

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(c);
            }
            public void Start() {
                c.Start();            
            }
            public void Stop() {
                c.Stop();
            }
        }
```

In the view I have 2 buttons that correspond to each controller action.

```
<button type="button">Start</button>
<button type="button">Stop</button>
```

How can I do the most correct way to call each controller action from the view buttons?

Thank you very much for your attention, I appreciate your help

Comment: `Start()` and `Stop()` would be controller actions which you call with AJAX. Also remember each request creates a new controller instance so that Song instance is also lost after the action has executed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use set `href` path to call your `controller` from `view`.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Start", "DefaultController")">Start</a>
```

and if want to pass parameter then:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Start","DefaultController", new {id=Item.id })">Start</a>
```

or for other options you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503923/html-button-calling-an-mvc-controller-and-action-method)

you can call your controller method using `ajax` also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186083/making-a-simple-ajax-call-to-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to achieve this is by using Razor as shown below:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Start", "DefaultController")'">Start</button> 

  <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Stop", "DefaultController")'">Stop</button>
```