# call to function from the controller in index.html

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my mvc app I have combobox, I am trying to do the following: when the user choose some item that will call to some function from the controller.

**Index.html:**

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("dor", "Home", new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "Get",
                        //UpdateTargetId = "myPic",
                        InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace
                    }))
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileName, Model.Files, new { Name = "map", @class = "form-control", onchange = "CallChangefunc()" })
                    }

.
.
.

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function CallChangefunc() {
     window.location.href = '@Url.Action("dor","Home")';
 }
 </script>
```

**HomeVM:**

```
public class HomeVM
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Files { get; set; }
    public string SelectedFileName { get; internal set; }
    public List<string> DynamicAlgorithems { get; set; }
}
```

**Homecontroller:**

```
public void dor()
{
       //some code    
}
```

The problem: when the user choose some item from combobox it redirect me to blank page i.e to `http://localhost:55354/Home/dor`, but I only want to call the function named `dor`, not to go to blank page!.

what am I missing?

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2503923/9114020)

Comment: Then make an ajax call, not redirect to it using `location.href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href` always redirect to a new page URL assigned to it. You should use `jQuery.ajax()` to call the action method when `onchange` method triggered and return desired result:

**jQuery (inside `$(document).ready()`)**

```
$('#SelectedFileName').change(function() {
    var selectedFileName = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("Dor", "Home")',
        data: { fileName: selectedFileName },
        success: function (result) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Dor(string fileName)
{
    // do something
}
```

**Note:** Make sure that action method argument has same name with assigned `data` passed from AJAX callback.