# Redirecting by buttonclick in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple issue in my asp.net core mvc project.

I have a button in one of my views, and when this button is clicked, I want to redirect to a specific controller, and a action in this controller.

Currently it looks like this:

```
<button  class="dropbtn" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> something</button>
```

I've been looking around for methods of doing this, and one of the solutions I found, was the `@Html.ActionLink("pik", "Index", "Home")`.

So I tried:

```
 <button onclick="@Html.ActionLink("pik", "Index", "Home")" class="dropbtn" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> Log in </button>
```

However this is just displayed as raw html. Does'nt work.

Then, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503923/html-button-calling-an-mvc-controller-and-action-method) I found this:

<button  nclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>'" class="dropbtn" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> Log in

However, my IDE just gives a bunch of `unexpected token` in this line. I don't undestand it either.

I then found this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" class="dropbtn" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">Submit</button>
}
```

This works in terms of the button, but for some reason, when I wrap the button in a form, my styling gets messed up.

I would rather not use javascript for redirecting.

So how can I redirect to a controller action with a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.ActionLink()` creates an html link with an `<a>` tag. If you are using Bootstrap (highly recommended) you can use this.

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")' class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">Click Me</a>
```

or if you want to use helpers, like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("pik", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user" })
```

This is the cleanest way I know of to create button with a link.

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link) out.